# bash script to get files from ftp server and rename files after downloading

Tags: php, linux, bash, ftp

I would like to create a bash script or PHP script to download CSV files from ftp server and add *.bak extension after downloadind files. I will execute automatically by cron job every 10 minutes.

I start with:

```
#!/bin/bash    
HOST=XXX.YYY.ZZZ.OOO
USERFTP=user
PASSWORD=xxx
PORT=2222
cd /home/sysadmin/testftp
ftp -inv $HOST 2222 <<EOF
quote USER $USERFTP
quote PASS $PASSWORD
cd  /home/ftp/
```

and I need to include thise "for" loop

```
for f in $(ls) do
if [ $(echo $f|egrep '\.(csv|CSV)$') ]
then
mget $f
mv $f $f.bak
fi
done`
```

I don't know how included the loop into bash script or if it's easier to create a php script ?

```
<?php
$local_file = 'local.zip';
$server_file = 'server.zip';
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);
$local_file
if (ftp_get($conn_id, $local_file, $server_file, FTP_BINARY)) {
echo "Le fichier $local_file a été écris avec succès\n";
} else {
echo "error\n";
}
ftp_close($conn_id);
?>
```

How can I include the for loop into php script ?

Regards :-)

Comment: Do you want a recommendation whether to prefer one approach over the other?

Comment: scp or rsync might be simpler then ftping, if you choose ftp your want to do it in either php or bash not both..

Comment: it is possible to run ftp in a coprocess and send commands anre read its responses. but CurlFtpFs is probably a better solution

Comment: you appear to be using mget to download a single file - why?

Answer (score -1):

```
#!/bin/bash 
curlftpfs  user@ftp.server.com:2222 /mnt/ftp
cd /mnt/ftp
for f in $(ls) do
if [ $(echo $f|egrep '\.(csv|CSV)$') ]
then
scp $f scp -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa sysadmin@10.100.0.100:/home/ipad
mv $f $f.bak
fi
fusermount -u /mnt/ftp
done
```

Looks good for you ?

Comment: It would be more helpful if you explain what this is actually doing, that way the OP learns what's going on and understands it :)

Comment: Actually it's not an answer to OPs question: "How can I include the for loop into php script ?"

Comment: I would like only copy and rename files from ftp server ! so the best way is curlftps I think.